# Freeware/open source program to convert MP3 to sheet music/notation

Tags: windows, gratis, music-production, music-composing, music-recognition

I am looking for a free or open source app (not paid/commercial/trial etc.) that can convert a mp3 or other audio file to a sheet music/notation Something comparable to [Audioscore](http://www.neuratron.com/audioscore.htm), but must be a free or open-source and compatible with Windows 7 x86_64.

Comment: While the raw idea is clear, your question is missing some details: asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) plus the questions linked to it for details, and see if you can [edit] and improve your question. The better you describe your needs, the better answers can match them.